# Why windows is throwing an Firewall alert when downloading a file via a thread and not when when downloading from main thread?

Tags: delphi, firewall, indy

Why windows is throwing an Firewall alert when downloading a file via a thread and not when when downloading from main thread ? Both code are identical !

How can I get rid of this ? (my users have only the "User with power right").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: it doesn't.

Long answer: the reason you're seeing this warning is probably unrelated to threading but rather with what you do in your thread. You haven't given any detail (not even the protocol used) so it's impossible to give accurate answer but, for instance, using active FTP for transferring a file will trigger a firewall warning while doing the same thing in passive mode will not.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I forgot to set the Active FTP transfert to false.

Comment: Wow! You saved my day @Stephane ! Passive mode doesn't trigger firewall alert! I didn't know about that and I was helpless in downloading a file. Thanks so much!!! BTW: why is it so?

Comment: @Enriqe That's because of the way FTP works. Check out the RFC for details but, basically, active FTP transfer works by having the server initiate a new TCP connection back to the client. This is typically not firewall-friendly so passive FTP was designed: the client opens a second TCP connection to the server instead.